# boost::spirit::qi performance

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have following snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace classic = boost::spirit::classic;

template<typename T>
void output_time(const T& end, const T& begin)
{
   std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
         end - begin).count() << std::endl;
}

template<typename Iter>
struct qi_grammar : public qi::grammar<Iter>
{
   qi_grammar():qi_grammar::base_type(rule_)
   {
      rule_ = *string_;
      string_ = qi::char_('"') >> *(qi::char_ - '"') >> qi::char_('"');
   }
   qi::rule<Iter> rule_;
   qi::rule<Iter> string_;
};

template<typename Iter>
struct classic_grammar : public classic::grammar<classic_grammar<Iter>>
{
   template<typename ScannerT>
   struct definition
   {
      definition(const classic_grammar&)
      {
         rule = *string_;
         string_ = classic::ch_p('"') >> *(classic::anychar_p - '"') >> classic::ch_p('"');
      }
      classic::rule<ScannerT> rule, string_;
      const classic::rule<ScannerT>& start() const { return rule; }
   };
};

template<typename Iter>
void parse(Iter first, Iter last, const qi_grammar<Iter>& prs)
{
   auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
   {
      Iter next = first;
      if (!qi::parse(next, last, prs) || next != last)
      {
         assert(false);
      }
   }
   auto finish = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   output_time(finish, start);
}

template<typename Iter>
void parse_c(Iter first, Iter last, const classic_grammar<Iter>& prs)
{
   auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
   {
      auto info = classic::parse(first, last, prs);
      if (!info.hit) assert(false);
   }
   auto finish = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   output_time(finish, start);
}

int main()
{
   qi_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> qi_lexeme;
   classic_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> classic_lexeme;
   std::stringstream ss;
   for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 500; ++i)
   {
      ss << "\"name\"";
   }
   const std::string s = ss.str();
   std::cout << "Size: " << s.size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Qi" << std::endl;
   parse(s.begin(), s.end(), qi_lexeme);
   std::cout << "Classic" << std::endl;
   parse_c(s.begin(), s.end(), classic_lexeme);
}
```

results are

```
forever@pterois:~/My_pro1/cpp_pro$ ./simple_j 
Size: 3072000
Qi
0
Classic
1
```

so, qi parse faster than classic. But when i change attribute of string_ rule to std::string() (i.e. `qi::rule<Iter, std::string()> string_;`) i have

```
forever@pterois:~/My_pro1/cpp_pro$ ./simple_j 
Size: 3072000
Qi
19
Classic
1
```

It's very-very slow. I doing something wrong? Thanks.

compiler:gcc 4.6.3. boost - 1.48.0. flags: -std=c++0x -O2. On LWS results are same.

Usage of semantic actions for char_ i.e.

```
string_ = qi::char_('"') >> *(qi::char_[boost::bind(&some_f, _1)] - '"')
 >> qi::char_('"')[boost::bind(&some_clear_f, _1)];
```

improve perfomance, but i'm looking for another solution too, if it exists.

Comment: What compiler? What compiler flags (optimization etc)?

Comment: @IgorR. gcc 4.6.3. -std=c++0x and -O2

Comment: Seems like your question is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343874/boost-spirit-qi-slow

Comment: @IgorR. hm... mb, but answers for its question cannot help me. since i'm already using -O2 + i'm trying to use qi::repeat - results are same... handle strings as chars is not solution for me.

Comment: @IgorR. mm... i'm not right, i think... semantic actions for store this chars looks like one of possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I answered a very similar question one before on SO. Sadly, I can't find it.

In short, you might prefer to use iterators into the source data instead of allocating (and copying) strings on each match.

When using

```
qi::rule<Iter, boost::iterator_range<Iter>()> string_;
string_ = qi::raw [ qi::char_('"') >> *(qi::char_ - '"') >> qi::char_('"') ];
```

I got (with considerably (16x) larger data set):

```
Size: 49152000
Qi
12
Classic
11
```

In fact, after changing the rule itself to

```
  string_ = qi::raw [ qi::lit('"') >> *~qi::char_('"') >> '"' ];
```

I got

```
Size: 49152000
Qi
7
Classic
11
```

So... that's pretty decent, I suppose. See it on LWS: [http://liveworkspace.org/code/opA5s$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/opA5s%240)

> For completeness, obviously you can get a string from the iterator_range by doing something like
>
> > ```
> > const std::string dummy("hello world");
> > auto r = boost::make_iterator_range(begin(dummy), end(dummy));
> > std::string asstring(r.begin(), r.end());
> > ```

The trick is to delay actual string construction to *when it's needed*. You might want to have this trick happen *automatically*. This is what `Spirit Lex` does for token attributes. You might want to look into that.

Comment: **edited** with a clarification and an optimization that saves ~40% of the runtime, making the `Qi` version ***vastly*** superior (1/3rd faster than `classic`). (Note I used gcc 4.7.2, 64bit, -O3 -march=native [-ltcmalloc](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/?redir=1) on a Q9550 with 8Mb of RAM) - see also [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+tcmalloc) for info on `libtcmalloc`

Comment: oh... i don't know about raw directive. thank you very much. I think, this will be answer for my question.